# Sendgrid connecting to Rails Issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, sendgrid

Im having issues with using sendgrid with my rails app on heroku. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong, or give me any pointers on how I could debug what is going wrong?

my config/environments/production file includes:

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'mydomain.com' }
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  :user_name      => 'apikey',
  :password       => Rails.application.credentials.sendgrid[:api_key],
  :domain         => 'mydomain.com',
  :address        => 'smtp.sendgrid.net',
  :port           => '587',
  :authentication => :plain,
  :enable_starttls_auto => true
}
```

Im getting a 500 error. In my development environment I used the letter opener gem and everything worked great. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you share the error message?

Comment: Net::SMTPFatalError (550 The from address does not match a verified Sender Identity. Mail cannot be sent until this error is resolved. Visit https://sendgrid.com/docs/for-developers/sending-email/sender-identity/ to see the Sender Identity requirements

Comment: I didnt see this. I will try and read the docs to figure it out. Sorry still learning.

Comment: No worries. Once you verify the sender in Sender Authentication settings, you should be good to go.

Comment: I also having this,

Comment: I'm having this with a Verified Sender created - any advice?